# Python unittest: how to nicely mock a web crawler function?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I wrote a small program in Python which output depends on the content of a few webpages. I have no control over these webpages and it could change in future. For so I am writing some tests.

I wrote an integration test and I am trying to write a `unittest` in which I mock the function scrapping the webpages. In my test the function is called twice and returns the content of two different webpages each time. This implies that I need to mock it with a function returning two different things. I am doing it the following way:

```
def gen():
    yield open("search_content.dat","rb").read()
    yield open("feed_content.dat","rb").read()
content_generator = gen()
def FakeScrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    return next(content_generator)
```

and further

```
@patch( "http.client.HTTPResponse.read", side_effect=FakeScrapper)
def test_mockscrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

I am using a function wrapping a generator. It looks quite heavy and ugly to me. Is there a more pythonic way of doing so?

Comment: it should be `def test_mockscrapper(self, mock_read)` to me under `@patch` line, as long as you have control over the which file your read, it is great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the generator straight away as a generator is an iterator and [side effect accepts an iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class):

> If side_effect is an iterable then each call to the mock will return
>   the next value from the iterable

In your example:

```
@patch( "http.client.HTTPResponse.read", side_effect=gen())
def test_mockscrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

Another simple example:

```
import os

from mock import patch,Mock

def gen():
    yield 1
    yield 2

class SimpleTest():

    @patch('os.dir', Mock(side_effect=gen()))
    def test_gen(self):
        a = os.dir()
        b = os.dir()
        assert a == 1
        assert b == 2
```

Comment: Many thanks. I did not know side_effect could be a generator. Good design flexibility.